# Promises.all() tracking invidual tasks completion

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm using `Promise.all(tasks)` to track the overall completion of my tasks executed in no particular order (which is my main aim). I also want to track individual tasks completion, how do I do that?

Comment: What do you mean, individual? One of the tasks completed? Or exact task completed?

Comment: *track* - and do what with the information (which information exactly)?

Comment: Just install individual `then` handlers on each of the promises?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Use `[/* array of promises */].map()` as parameter to `Promise.all()` ? "track" each `Promise` within `.map()` callback ?

Comment: @Bergi then will force my tasks to run sequentially... I don't want TaskA to wait till TaskB completes, you are missing the point.

Comment: @user1514042: `then` doesn't force any sequence, unless you're creating TaskB in the callback of TaskA - which is not what I was referring to.

Comment: @Bergi makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing keeps you from attaching individual handlers as well awaiting them together:

```
let tasks = …;
for ([t, i] of tasks.entries())
    t.then(res => {
        console.log("task "+i+" completed with", res);
    }, err => {
        console.log("task "+i+" failed because", err);
    });
Promise.all(tasks).then(all => {
    console.log("all tasks completed");
}, err => {
    console.log("something failed");
});
```

Comment: would then() not force sequential execution?

Comment: Yes, it would force the `console.log`s to run after the respective promise settles. It doesn't force any order between the promises. Just try it on your `tasks`!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Array.prototype.map()` to pass promises to `Promise.all()`

```js
var promises = [Promise.resolve("a"), Promise.resolve("b")];

Promise.all(promises.map(function(p, index) {
  return p.then(function(data) {
    console.log("inside .map()", data, "index", index)
    return data
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return err
  })
}))
.then(function(complete) {
  console.log("all promises after .map()", complete)
}, function(err) {
  console.log("err", err)
})
```

Comment: That'll hardly ever hit `console.log("err", err)` early-reject, as you're handling all errors

Comment: @Bergi Can describe "hardly ever hit console.log("err", err)" ? Will not reach `onRejected` of `.then` following `.all()` ?

Comment: Yes, it will not reach it when any of the `promises` is rejected.

Comment: @Bergi Interestingly just tried with second promise converted to `.reject("b")` , `"all promises after .map() ["a", "b"]"` logged at `.then` `onFulfilled` https://jsfiddle.net/9gprLc7q/ ? Would expect expect `console.log("err", err)` to be called ? Any insight ?

Comment: @Bergi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042068/why-is-onrejected-not-called-following-promise-all-where-promise-reject-incl