# Why is onRejected not called following Promise.all() where Promise.reject() included in array passed to Promise.all()?

Tags: javascript, promise

Given

```js
var promises = [Promise.resolve("a"), Promise.reject("b")];

Promise.all(promises.map(function(p, index) {
  return p.then(function(data) {
    console.log("inside .map()", data, "index", index)
    return data
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return err
  })
}))
.then(function(complete) {
  console.log("all promises after .map()", complete)
}, function(err) {
  console.log("err", err)
})
```

why is `onRejected` not called at `.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)` following `Promise.all()` ?

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9gprLc7q/

https://jsfiddle.net/9gprLc7q/

Comment: because you don't handle the error in the mapping, what you return is still resolved promise. if you do `Promise.reject(err)` it will work properly.

Comment: Closely related if not even duplicate (but not an obvious one): [Chained promises not passing on rejection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16371129/1048572). You `return err` instead of re`throw`ing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've really done here is something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/9gprLc7q/5/

```
var notRejectedPromise = 
    Promise.reject("b")
      .then((resolved) => resolved, (err) => err)

var promises = [Promise.resolve("a"), notRejectedPromise];

Promise.all(promises)
.then(function(complete) {
  console.log("all promises after .map()", complete)
}, function(err) {
  console.log("err", err)
})
```

But deciding to handle the err portion by returning whatever `err` was, you returned a string. This is not a reason for rejection.

To actually cause the `Promise.all()` to reject you need an error to occur in either the `resolved` or `rejected` portion of `.then`

Given this, if you **return** a rejected promise, it will reject:

https://jsfiddle.net/9gprLc7q/3/

```
console.log(err)
```

to

```
return Promise.reject(err)
```

Alternatively you can throw an error: https://jsfiddle.net/9gprLc7q/2/

```
console.log(err)
```

to

```
throw new Error(err)
```

Comment: Why does removing `.then()` at `.map()` return expected results  https://jsfiddle.net/9gprLc7q/4/ ? Why is rejected `Promise` converted to resolved `Promise` ?

Comment: @guest271314 this is because you never attached a `.then` to the rejected promise. So now instead of returning `"b"`, which isn't a reject, it returns itself `Promise.reject("b")` which is a rejected value.

Comment: @guest271314 maybe this will help https://jsfiddle.net/9gprLc7q/5/. The err portion returns a string instead of a `Promise.reject` when you do `return err` in your original code

Comment: Returned expected results using only `throw err` https://jsfiddle.net/9gprLc7q/6/ , without `new Error(err)`

Comment: @guest271314 Yeah that's another topic to talk about haha. From what I've read `throw new Error(err)` is a better alternative to `throw err`, but they both basically do the same thing. Do you understand now?

Comment: _"From what I've read throw new Error(err) is a better alternative to throw err"_ Appears on-topic from vantage, here. Links to discussion have read on this topic ? _"Do you understand now?"_ Yes

Comment: @guest271314 here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156176/javascript-what-is-the-difference-in-throw-new-error-and-throwobject :D

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand that handling a rejection results in putting the promise back on the success path. One approach to this is to re-throw in the failure handler, like this:

```
var promises = [Promise.resolve("a"), Promise.reject("b")];

Promise.all(promises.map(function(p, index) {
  return p.then(function(data) {
    console.log("inside .map()", data, "index", index)
    return data
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);

    // RE-THROW!!
    throw err;                  

  })
}))
.then(...
```

If the purpose of the rejection handler is merely to log, then you could move it out of the chain:

```
Promise.all(promises.map(function(p, index) {

  // MOVE ERROR HANDLER OUTSIDE OF CHAIN
  p.catch(function(e) { console.log(e); });

  return p.then(function(data) {
    console.log("inside .map()", data, "index", index)
    return data
  })
}))
.then(...
```

Comment: I touched upon this but edited it out. Thanks for phrasing it even better than I did :D