# Handle both resolved promises

Tags: javascript

Say I have a promise and I use .then to wait for it to resolve,

```
var suc = function(){ console.log('promise ended') } 
var err = function(e){ console.log('promise ended') }

promise.then( suc, err );
>> promise ended
>> promise ended
```

What if I do not care if It succedes or fails? I just want to know it was completed.

```
promise.both(function(){console.log('next')}
```

Is there such a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
promise.catch(function() {}).then(function() { console.log('DONE'); });
```

Answer (score 2):

Could use `.then()` prior to calling `suc` or `err`

```
var completed = function() { console.log('next') };

promise.then(completed, completed).then(suc, err)
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042068/why-is-onrejected-not-called-following-promise-all-where-promise-reject-incl