# Does "resolve" consistently mean something distinct from "fulfill"?

Tags: javascript, terminology, es6-promise

(Related but not quite the same: [JS Promises: Fulfill vs Resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35398365/js-promises-fulfill-vs-resolve))

I've been trying to wrap my head around Javascript promises, and I'm struggling with the basic notions of *resolve* and *resolved*, vs. *fulfill* and *fulfilled*. I have read several introductions, such as [Jake Archibald's](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises), as well as browsing [some](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-objects) [relevant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) [specs](https://promisesaplus.com/).

In [States and Fates](https://github.com/domenic/promises-unwrapping/blob/master/docs/states-and-fates.md) (not quite an official spec, but referenced as an authoritative document written by one of the spec authors), *fulfilled* is a state while *resolved* is a "fate" (whatever that is -- but they're clearly distinct):

> Promises have three possible mutually exclusive states: fulfilled,
>   rejected, and pending.
>
> - A promise is **fulfilled** if `promise.then(f)` will call f "as soon as
>     possible."

and

> A promise is *resolved* if trying to **resolve** or **reject** it has no effect,
>   i.e. the promise has been "locked in" to either follow another
>   promise, or has been **fulfilled** or **rejected**

In particular, *resolved* encompasses both *fulfilled* and *rejected* (and *locked in*). The "opposite" (or directly corresponding function) to *reject* is *fulfill*, not *resolve*; *resolve* **includes** *reject* as one of its possibilities.

Yet the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-objects) refers to the first argument to the `then()` method (or its corresponding abstract concepts) using both *fulfill* and *resolve*:

- > 25.4: A promise p is **fulfilled** if p.then(**f**, r) will immediately enqueue a Job to call the function f.
- > 25.4.1.1: [[**Resolve**]]   A function object   The function that is used to **resolve** the given promise object.
- > 25.4.1.3: Set the [[Promise]] internal slot of **resolve** to promise.
  >   Set the [[AlreadyResolved]] internal slot of **resolve** to alreadyResolved. [Then immediately after, *reject* is used in an exactly corresponding way.]
- > 25.4.5.3: Promise.prototype.then ( **onFulfilled** , onRejected )

Maybe one of the most crucial is

- > 25.4.4.5 Promise.**resolve** ( x )

which [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) describes as follows:

> The **Promise.resolve(value)** method returns a Promise object that is resolved with the given value. If the value is a thenable (i.e. has a "then" method), the returned promise will "follow" that thenable, adopting its eventual state; otherwise the returned promise will be **fulfilled** with the value.

There is no mention of the `Promise.resolve()` method having the potential to *reject*.  Furthermore, there is a `Promise.reject()` method, but no `Promise.fulfill()` method. So here, the counterpart to *reject* is *resolve*, instead of *fulfill*.

Granted, there might be no guaranteed correlation between the "fate" term *resolved*, and the method (or verb) *resolve*.  But it would be (is?) really misleading and confusing to have `resolve()` put a promise into a specifically *fulfilled* state, when the terms *fulfilled* and *resolved* have carefully been defined to have distinct meanings.

Is that what has happened here... the right hand didn't know what the left hand was doing, and we ended up with the documents that are supposed to be the guiding lights of the movement using terms in inconsistent ways? Or is there something I'm missing, and *resolve* is actually a more appropriate term than *fulfill* for what the `resolve()` method does?

I don't mean to come across as critical of the document authors. I understand how, with a widely-distributed group, over history, it's difficult to get all the terms to be used consistently across all documents. My purpose here, in digging into the terminology and phrasing of these documents, is to understand the terms accurately -- which includes knowing the limits of how precisely terms like *fulfill* and *resolve* can really be distinguished. [Jake Archibald admits](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises#promise-terminology) that he sometimes gets the terms mixed up. That's a very helpful admission to noobs like me who are trying to make sense of terminology! Thank you, Jake, for being vulnerable. :-) My purpose in asking this question is to find out, which definitions or usages of those terms *are* reliable? Or should I conclude that *resolve* is sometimes used specifically to mean *fulfill*, and sometimes *fulfill/reject/lock in*, even in the most authoritative documents?

Comment: I agree that this inconsistent usage of fulfill(ed) vs resolv(ed) is a real annoyance, it tripped me up a couple of times when I first began using Promises. Having said that, I'm not sure there's an "answer", because it is what it is :p

Answer (score 3):

> I'm struggling with the basic notions of *resolve* and *resolved*, vs. *fulfill* and *fulfilled*.

Have a look at [What is the correct terminology for javascript promises](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29268569/1048572). Yes, they're sometimes mixed up, but let's try to ignore that.

> Yet the spec refers to the first argument to the `then()` method (or its corresponding abstract concepts) using both *fulfill* and *resolve*. Did we end up with the documents that are supposed to be the guiding lights of the movement using terms in inconsistent ways?

No, there is no inconsistency here, the terms in the spec are accurate.

*resolve* is not the opposite of *reject*, and the `onFulfilled` callback does not exactly correspond to *resolving*.

> Or is there something I'm missing, and *resolve* is actually a more appropriate term than *fulfill* for what the `resolve()` method does?

Yes. The problem is that you can *resolve* with a promise (or in general, a thenable, i.e. any object with a `then` method), and instead of fulfilling with that object the resolved promise will try to fulfill with the thenable's *result*. Or when the thenable has (will have) an error, it will reject with that as the reason.

> There is no mention [in MDN] of the `Promise.resolve()` method having the potential to *reject*.

Actually there is: "*the returned promise will "follow" that thenable, adopting its eventual state*". If that eventual state is the error state, then the returned promise will reject as well.

> There is a `Promise.reject()` method, but no `Promise.fulfill()` method. So here, the counterpart to *reject* is *resolve*, instead of *fulfill*.

Yes, ES6 promises are lacking a `Promise.fulfill` method. This is a bit inconsistent and confusing at first, but was done for a good reason: It prevents you from having a promise that is fulfilled with another promise. You can only *resolve* ES6 promises, and when you pass in a promise it will take its result not the promise object by itself.

This is pretty useful, but can be pretty inconvenient as well. There are libraries that do it better and allow this case, they're so-called "*algebraic promises*" (which you can reason about a lot better). [Creed](https://github.com/briancavalier/creed) is a good example of that, and its `Promise.of` method is a real counterpart to `Promise.reject`.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. When you say "resolve with X", "fulfill with X", or "reject with X", does that mean passing X as the parameter to the respective function? Or does "with X" mean different things in those three cases?

Comment: Also, in "and when you pass in a promise it will take its result not the promise object by itself" can you clarify the antecedents of the two *it*s, and elaborate on the word *take*? My guess is: "If you `resolve()` a promise, passing another promise as the argument to `resolve()`, the result of the first promise will be the *result* of the passed promise, not the passed promise object itself."

Comment: @LarsH Yes, that's exactly what I meant (in all cases).

Answer (score 1):

Let's add emphasis somewhere else in one of your quotes :

> A promise is resolved if trying to resolve or reject it has no effect, i.e. the promise has been "locked in" to either **follow another promise**, or has been fulfilled or rejected

`reject()` will change your Promise and all the prior-chained ones status to `rejected`.
While `resolve()` will lock your current Promise, but only the fulfillment of the resolving callbacks will set its status to `fulfilled`. As long as everything is not finished, your Promise will still be `'pending'`.

e.g If you do chain your Promise, and that during the chain, an error is thrown, then the state of your Promise is set to `'rejected'`.

```js
var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(); // here p is resolved, we can't call resolve() or reject() anymore
}).then((e) => { // chain it
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(p); // 'pending' because it's still chained
    reject('whatever') // this one throws an error and breaks the chain
  })
}).then(() => console.log('passed')); // won't happen


setTimeout(() => console.log(p, "please check in your browser's console"), 1000); // rejected
```

So even if you are `resolve()`-ing the current operation of your Promise, you can't know what will happen after, so you can't know if at the end it will be `fulfilled` or `rejected`.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is helpful, though I'm still not fully following the logic. When you say "but only the fulfillment of the resolving callbacks will set its status to `fulfilled`", what does *the resolving callbacks* refer to ... the function passed as the `resolve` argument to the function supplied to each Promise constructor?

Comment: @LarsH, I look at it as a chain. You resolve the first link, then the following ones. But every Promises in the chain will be fulfiled only if all links are resolved. If at one point a link breaks, the full chain os broken, all the promises will become rejected (no way to go to what was originally promised...)