# Does every ECMAScript runtime with await await any Thenable?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

The following currently logs `Yahtzee` in node, chrome, firefox.

As you can see, not even prototype of Promise was set.

```js
const fake = new Number(1)
fake.then = fn => setTimeout(fn, 0, 'Yahtzee')
const main = async () => {
  console.log(await fake)
}
main()
```

Does this works universally?
And more importantly, will this behavior likely persist?

Comment: Yes, that's how it is supposed to work, and it's implemented like that by the spec which is unlikely to change.

Comment: Technically, you can await any expression. `const main = async () => { console.log(await 3); }; main();` will log 3. Why would you want to? That's a different question. :)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, please note that the result of the await becomes "Yahtzee" and not 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this will work. [According to the specs](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#await), a new Promise will be called and resolve with that value. `Promise.resolve` works with thenable so it will work the same for `await`

So, the above is equivalent to

```
const fake = new Number(1)
fake.then = fn => setTimeout(fn, 0, 'Yahtzee')
const main = async () => {
  console.log(await Promise.resolve(fake))
}
main()
```

Where it is [the `.resolve()` method that calls `then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) on the object.

Comment: I tentatively added ad edit, please tell me if it is correct.
I tried to follow the spec, but I can't find where that is specified.
Where in `PromiseResolve` does it happen? Is it the `Call(promiseCapability.[[Resolve]], undefined, « x »)`? If it is, then where in `NewPromiseCapability` does it check for the `then` method?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve The beginning is good for how thenable works with promises

Comment: Excellent! I was hoping to understand the spec for once, though.
The Description is wrong :c
It says it **returns a Promise that is resolved**. Not only is it not always a resolved promise, but it can even reject :v
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve#Description

Comment: @MihailMalostanidis Maybe you misunderstood [what `resolve` means](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41910860/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi I doubt it, since I linked to the `Promise.resolve()` static method and not the first argument to the `executor` function.

Comment: @MihailMalostanidis The question I linked *is* about `Promise.resolve`. And there is hardly any difference, given that `Promise.resolve = function(x) { return new this(resolve => resolve(x)); }`