# Are method-chains self-aware?

Tags: promise, superagent

In the package [Super Agent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent), the docs state:

> A request can be initiated by invoking the appropriate method on the
> request object, then calling .then() (or .end() or await) to send the
> request.

```js
request
   .get('/search')
   .then(res => {
      // res.body, res.headers, res.status
   });
```

However SuperAgent supports method chaining such as

```js
request.get('/search')
  .set('header1','value')
  .set('header2','value')
```

to modify the request before it is sent.  So...

#### How does the request object know when the method chain is finished so it doesn't prematurely send?

My theory is that any chain off of the `request` object returns a thenable object which is able to be `await`'d or `.then()`'d, and when it is, it will fire off a request and return an actual promise.

I looked around in the superagent repo and couldn't find anything like that.  How else might waiting to send the request until the method chain is complete be accomplished?

Comment: Yes. As you quoted the docs, "*calling `.then()` or `.end()`*" does send the request.

Comment: Also [that's what the code does](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/5b86fd397264cb7b84634fa7ff00ad82214aa473/src/request-base.js#L238-L264)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never go wrong by just going to the source and looking.  So, if you look at [the code for `.then()`](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/master/src/request-base.js#L238), you will see that it calls `.end()` on itself.

So, the request is sent when `.then()` or `.end()` is called.  Up until then, other methods are just configuring the request object.

And, using `await` will invoke `.then()` on the promise.

Also, if you search for `.end` in that above source file reference, you will see dozens of code examples that all show `.end()` at the end of the chain.  That is the original design architecture for superagent.  Then, when promises came along, support for `.then()` was added and it uses `.end()` internally.

Comment: So does that mean that `await` sends it too because the object is `thenable`?

Comment: @Jordan - Yes.  `await` actually invokes `.then()` since that's the only way you know when a promise is done.

Comment: @Jordan `await` is no magic, it just [calls `.then` if the awaited object is thenable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49086056/1048572).