# Possible contradiction between Promises/A+ spec and ECMAScript promises?

Tags: javascript, promise

It is [asserted](https://promisesaplus.com/implementations#the-ecmascript-specification) the ECMAScript promises is a Promises/A+ implementation, so they have no contradictions. However, I encountered a behaviour of ecma promises which allegedly is out of line with the Promises/A+.

When we call `promise1.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)` to listen to the `promise1`'s output, we get as a return value another promise (`promise2`). When the needed callback (`onFulfilled/onRejected`) was executed and it, in turn, returned some value `x`, the spec prescribes to resolve it with the defined `[[Resolve(promise2, x)]]` function. Let's suppose `x` happened to be a **promise** itself (`x === promise3`), then [the steps](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-49) must be taken is the following:

> - If `x` is a promise, adopt its state:
> - If `x` is pending, `promise2` must remain pending until `x` is fulfilled or rejected.
> - If/when `x` is fulfilled, fulfill `promise2` with the same value.
> - If/when `x` is rejected, reject `promise2` with the same reason.

I wonder what if `x` is finally fulfilled with yet another promise (`promise4`) (there are not anything in the way of it, are there?). It can be concluded from the spec excerpt that `promise2` must be fulfilled with `promise4` too. But it is seemingly not so in the ECMAScript world:

```
let promise4 = new Promise((resolve) => { resolve(4) })

let promise3 = new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(promise4);
});

let promise1 = new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(1);
});

let promise2 = promise1.then((val) => { return promise3 });
promise2.then(val => console.log(val)); // output: 4
```

In the other words, `promise2` is fulfilled with the `promise4`'s value. This behaviour is like one that is defined in the spec for other `thenable` objects. So don't ECMAScript promises carry out expected type checking and just check whether `x` has `then` method?

Comment: _"...that `promise2` must be fulfilled with `promise4` too. But it is seemingly not so in the ECMAScript world"_ - As you mentioned yourself the output of `console.log(val)` is `4` which is the "value" of `promise4` so where's the problem?

Comment: @Andreas `promise3` (`x`) fulfilled with `promise4` not with `4`. The spec says `promise2` must be fulfilled with the value of `x` not with the value of `promise4`.

Comment: `promise3` is `promise4`, `promise2` is `promise3` -> `console.log(val)` logs `4` the "value" of `promise4`

Comment: @Andreas why is the value of `promise3` the value of `promise4` (that is `4`) and not the `promise4` itself? My misunderstanding is exactly here. Do you mean there is no difference between `resolve(4)` and `resolve(promise4)`? But I think it's not be drawed from the spec. Probably ECMAScript `resolve` cb is not a direct way to fulfill a promise I should delve into the ECMAScript spec..

Comment: _"The [`Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) method returns a `Promise` object that is resolved with a given value. If the value is a promise, that promise is returned; if the value is a thenable (i.e. has a ["`then`" method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)), the returned promise will "follow" that thenable, adopting its eventual state; otherwise the returned promise will be fulfilled with the value."_

Comment: [Native `Promise`s do not provide a way to fulfill a promise with another promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32168194/1048572). Promises/A+ leaves this unspecified. It does, after all, implement the proper thenable resolution procedure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's suppose `x` happened to be a promise itself, then the steps **must** be taken is the following: […]

No, they don't need to be taken - they only may be taken if `x` is a "promise". These steps are an optional ("allowed", not "required") optimisation:

> [Note 4](https://promisesaplus.com/#notes):
> Generally, it will only be known that `x` is a true promise if it comes from the current implementation. This clause **allows** the use of implementation-specific means to adopt the state of known-conformant promises.

ECMAScript does not treat its own `Promise`s as "known to be conformant", ignoring these steps. They simply treat native promises like all other thenables. Given there is [no way to create an ECMAScript `Promise` that is fulfilled with another promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32168194/1048572), this is equivalent to directly adopting the state.

Comment: `2.2.7.1 If either onFulfilled or onRejected returns a value x, run the Promise Resolution Procedure [[Resolve]](promise2, x).` There is no the word "must" too, does it mean `[[Resolve]]` is an optional function at all and an implementation may choose altogether different manner to process `x`?

Comment: @Mergasov No, the `then` method must follow that algorithm, but it can supply its own `IsKnownPromise` check.

Comment: Actually, I incline to think of that "allow" word as concerning means (the spec gives permission for an implementation to decide on what's under the hood of its `IsKnownPromise`) but not as allowing to ignore all those steps completely which I'd rather consider to be obligatory. Nevertheless, I've got the answer ECMAScript promises behave differently.

Comment: @Mergasov Agreed. ES6' decision to define `IsKnownPromise = () => false` is weird, and prevents lots of useful optimisation possibilities. [Personally I consider it a bug](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2015-April/042517.html), but so far, nobody seemed to care.

Answer (score 0):

> It can be concluded from the spec excerpt that `promise2` must be fulfilled with `promise4` too.

No, this does not follow from the Promises/A+ specification. The rule you quote from it

> - If/when `x` is fulfilled, fulfill `promise2` with the same value.

...is recursive in nature. It should be understood in more elaborate terms as follows:

*If/when `x` is fulfilled, fulfill `promise2` with the same value **that `x` fulfilled with.***

Now for the part *"that `x` fulfilled with"*, the same Resolution Procedure applies(!): Indeed, as `x` *resolves* with yet another thenable (`promise4`), it in turn gets locked-in with the next promise in the chain (`promise4` in your example). This is not yet the *fulfilled* value. -- there is an important difference between [resolving and fulfilling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35398365/js-promises-fulfill-vs-resolve/56850392#56850392). This second execution of the Resolution Procedure will make sure that the value that `x` *fulfils* with, is the value that `promise4` fulfils with.

The chain of locked-in promises can have any length, but the principle remains the same: each will resolve by locking into the next promise through this Promises/A+ Resolution Procedure. When the last one in this chain *fulfils* (with a non-thenable value), then all promises that are locked-in will get *fulfilled* with this value.

Comment: The resolution procedure is imperative, a setter, not a getter that finds a fulfillment value. The recursion you mention goes the other way round. The is no recursion in the statement "*fulfill `promise` with the fulfillment value of `x`*" of `[[resolve]](promise, x)` - it is a base case. Sure, something else might run `[[resolve]](x, y)`, but that's unrelated.

Comment: The resolution procedure is executed in a forward direction. I don't suggest that a fulfilment value is found via a getter. It is set by the last one in the chain, affecting all locked in promises. BTW, the Promises/A+ specification speaks itself of *"the recursive nature of `[[Resolve]](promise, thenable)`"*.

Comment: Yes, fulfilling one promise `x` does fulfill the other promises that were resolved with `x`, via the clause you quoted. But I don't see where the recursion is. The promise `x` might be resolved in any other way as well, not only through the promise resolution procedure - it only applies to promises created from `then()` calls. The recursive nature of the procedure refers only to resolving with a thenable (which might call the callback with another thenable argument).