# Specs about eager evaluation of Promise callbacks

Tags: javascript, promise, specifications

Is there a spec / implementation detail on how "eager" is the evaluation of the callbacks of a promise?
I mean, let's say that I have

```js
var promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
   resolve()
});

console.log(promise); // there is no public field '<state>', but you can see it in the console of the dev tools
```

I see that `promise` is already fulfilled; I was expecting that the `Promise` internal implementation would call the `resolve` callback on an following time, leaving a "time window" with `promise` still unfulfilled.

Is this "eager" evaluation of the `resolve` callback "by design"? Is this just an implementation detail?

Comment: is it resolved though? - `promise` in that code is forever pending, as it is never fulfilled nor rejected

Comment: by the way, the function you pass to new Promise is run immediately - the promise returned can be fulfilled or rejected in that callback by calling the passed in functions (the first fulfills and the second rejects - the convention, for some reason, is `function(resolve, reject) {}`) - however, yor "resolve" function takes no arguments, so can't possibly effect the state of the Promise, hence it will be forever pending

Comment: Turned your code into a snippet and added a `then` call. This demonstrates that the promise is **not** resolved.

Comment: That's a bit misleading @trincot - a Promise is either `pending`, `fulfilled` or `rejected` :p - my pet hate with Promises is that the "onFulfilled" callback is ALWAYS named "resolve" in almost every codebase ... I'm a rebel, I call it `fulfil` :p

Comment: @Bravo, resolving has a meaning of its own right. A promise can be resolved without being yet defined whether it will fulfil or reject. This happens when it is "locked in". [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35398365/js-promises-fulfill-vs-resolve/56850392#56850392) I have on this terminology. So calling the callback `fulfil` is not really covering its use better.

Comment: my example was wrong, I want to understand if the resolve callback of the executor is executed eagerly or not

Comment: @trincot - very good point - hadn't thought of that!

Comment: @VitoDeTullio - it is called immediately, not eagerly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callback passed to the Promise constructor is executed synchronously by that constructor. So when the `new` operator returns the constructed object, the callback has already run.

This is by the [ECMA Script specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-promise-executor). The procedure for `new Promise(excecutor)` describes in step 9 that the executor is called and in step 11 that the constructed promise object is returned.

Mozilla Contributors [write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise):

> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> new Promise(executor)
> ```
>
> #### Parameters
>
> ```
> executor
> ```
>
> A function to be executed by the constructor, during the process of constructing the new `Promise` object.

The constructor callback function is typically used to initiate an asynchronous process (by relying on an asynchronous API, like `setTimeout`), which can resolve the promise at a time that the constructor callback has already returned.

```
function executor(resolve) { 
    setTimeout(resolve, 100);
}

var promise = new Promise(executor);
```

In your example, that callback does not rely an such asynchronous API, but synchronously calls the `resolve` callback. That means that when the constructed promise object is assigned to your `promise` variable, that promise is already in a fulfilled state.

Comment: which beggers the question, why does OP state that the promise is fulfilled!

Comment: @Bravo It isn't. Probably they meant that their `resolve` function (i.e. executor) was called...

Comment: ahh, @FZs - how could they tell that? it's an empty function :p

Comment: no, I mean that the promise is fulfilled. as in: I open the debug tools, evaluate new Promise( resolve => resolve()); and I see `{ <state>: "fulfilled", <value>: undefined }`

Comment: Vito, I see you have updated your question's code after I posted my answer, so I have updated my answer accordingly.