# Why do I have to use await to get the result of the promise?

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

async function notInstant() {
  await delay(1);
  return 1;
}

(async function() {
 let a = notInstant();
 console.log(a);
 await delay(10000);
 console.log("Still a promise after 10 seconds even though the function only waits for 1 millisecond =>", a);
 a = await a;
 console.log("Printing directly after but now is resolved with the correct value", a);
})();
```

I know that I shouldn't rely on setTimeout for these kinds of things, but I don't understand why printing the result after 10 seconds still gives an unresolved promise even though the function called only waits for 1 millisecond before returning a value.
Then using await makes the result directly available for some reason.

Comment: notInstant() returns a Promise.  Asking why a Promise is still a Promise after 10 seconds is like asking why an int is still an int after 10 seconds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS Promises: Fulfill vs Resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35398365/js-promises-fulfill-vs-resolve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example illustrates the principle you're observing:

```
let a = {};
console.log(a);
a.val = 1;
console.log(typeof a); // still an object even though `a` has a value
a = a.val;
console.log(typeof a); // now it's a number
```

The original promise returned from `notInstant` will always be a promise. `await` basically extracts the resolved value from the promise for you. The only reason `a` ends up being a value in your example is that you're setting it to the result of the `await` expression.

If you wanted to set `a` to the result of its promise when it completes, but avoid `await`ing it, you could use its `then` method to affect a state change, like this:

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

async function notInstant() {
  await delay(1);
  return 1;
}

(async function() {
 let a = notInstant();
 console.log(a);
 a.then(n => a = n);
 await delay(1000); 
 console.log("a has its value now; we waited long enough", a);
})();
```

That's probably not a great pattern to follow (reusing the variable to represent both the promise and the value), but hopefully it helps teach the principle.

Answer (score 1):

from the docs:

> The await expression causes async function execution to pause until a
> Promise is settled (that is, fulfilled or rejected), and to resume
> execution of the async function after fulfillment. When resumed, the
> value of the await expression is that of the fulfilled Promise.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

So, as mentioned by DaveG, with out calling the await, you are just holding the promise

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `async functions` return a promise.
And you need `await` to get the value of the promise.

---

here is what [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) says about it:

#### [Async Function's Return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#return_value)

A [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which will be resolved with the value returned by the async function, or rejected with an exception thrown from, or uncaught within, the async function.

Answer (score 0):

when you use await function(),
the function should return a promise,
and if you put await and the result return by that function is not promise
the await does not have any effect.
so you need to tell js to await for the result and give it a promise when you gonna return in two cases of resolve or reject.
[check MDN Documention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)