# The execution order of the promise according to the return type

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, return, order-of-execution

I would like to know the reason why the execution order varies depending on what is returned in a `then` callback:

```js
var a = Promise.resolve();

var b = a.then(function a_then() {
  console.log(1);
  var c = Promise.resolve();
  var d = c.then(function c_then() {
    console.log(2);
  });
  var e = d.then(function d_then() {
    console.log(3);
  });
  console.log(4);

  return c; // <--- this influences the output order

});

var f = b.then(function b_then() {
  console.log(5);
  var g = Promise.resolve();
  var h = g.then(function g_then() {
    console.log(6);
  });
  var i = h.then(function h_then() {
    console.log(7);
  });
  console.log(8);
});

console.log(9);
```

Without that `return c` (so returning `undefined`), the output order is: 9,1,4,2,5,8,3,6,7 and this order was explained as an answer to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76528242/5459839).

But adding that `return c` changes the output order to 9,1,4,2,3,5,8,6,7.

Why is the value 3 now output before values 5 and 8? Why is the order of the events like this?

NB: A similar change in output happens when returning `d` or `e`.

It would be very nice if you could explain it using the table that was used as [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76530114/5459839) to my previous question:

| Task | Action | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | PromiseJob queue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Script | `a = Promise.resolve()` | **F** | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |  |
| Script | `b = a.then(a_then)` | F | **?** | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | **`a_then`** |
| Script | `f = b.then(b_then)` | F | ? | - | - | - | **?** | - | - | - | `a_then` |
| Script | **`console.log(9)`** | F | ? | - | - | - | ? | - | - | - | `a_then` |
| Host | dequeue `a_then` | F | ? | - | - | - | ? | - | - | - |  |
| `a_then` | **`console.log(1)`** | F | ? | - | - | - | ? | - | - | - |  |
| `a_then` | `c = Promise.resolve()` | F | ? | **F** | - | - | ? | - | - | - |  |
| `a_then` | `d = c.then(c_then)` | F | ? | F | **?** | - | ? | - | - | - | **`c_then`** |
| `a_then` | `e = d.then(d_then)` | F | ? | F | ? | **?** | ? | - | - | - | `c_then` |
| `a_then` | **`console.log(4)`** | F | ? | F | ? | ? | ? | - | - | - | `c_then` |
| `a_then` | return resolves `b` | F | **F** | F | ? | ? | ? | - | - | - | `c_then`, **`b_then`** |
| Host | dequeue `c_then` | F | F | F | ? | ? | ? | - | - | - | `b_then` |
| `c_then` | **`console.log(2)`** | F | F | F | ? | ? | ? | - | - | - | `b_then` |
| `c_then` | return resolves `d` | F | F | F | **F** | ? | ? | - | - | - | `b_then`, **`d_then`** |
| Host | dequeue `b_then` | F | F | F | F | ? | ? | - | - | - | `d_then` |
| `b_then` | **`console.log(5)`** | F | F | F | F | ? | ? | - | - | - | `d_then` |
| `b_then` | `g = Promise.resolve()` | F | F | F | F | ? | ? | **F** | - | - | `d_then` |
| `b_then` | `h = g.then(g_then)` | F | F | F | F | ? | ? | F | **?** | - | `d_then`, **`g_then`** |
| `b_then` | `i = h.then(h_then)` | F | F | F | F | ? | ? | F | ? | **?** | `d_then`, `g_then` |
| `b_then` | **`console.log(8)`** | F | F | F | F | ? | ? | F | ? | ? | `d_then`, `g_then` |
| `b_then` | return resolves `f` | F | F | F | F | ? | **F** | F | ? | ? | `d_then`, `g_then` |
| Host | dequeue `d_then` | F | F | F | F | ? | F | F | ? | ? | `g_then` |
| `d_then` | **`console.log(3)`** | F | F | F | F | ? | F | F | ? | ? | `g_then` |
| `d_then` | return resolves `e` | F | F | F | F | **F** | F | F | ? | ? | `g_then` |
| Host | dequeue `g_then` | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | ? | ? |  |
| `g_then` | **`console.log(6)`** | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | ? | ? |  |
| `g_then` | return resolves `h` | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | **F** | ? | **`h.then`** |
| Host | dequeue `h_then` | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | ? |  |
| `h_then` | **`console.log(7)`** | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | ? |  |
| `h_then` | return resolves `i` | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | **F** |  |
| Host | queue is empty | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | F |  |

Comment: your code doesn't even run ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ - as for that table ... wth does it even mean? what's `F` whats **`F`** what's `?` what's `a`, `b`, `c` ... `j`? what do you need in `PromiseJob queue`

Comment: once you make the code you posted executable, your output is always 9 1 4 2 5 8 3 6 7 - not sure what you want to do with all those cases

Comment: Please focus your question on **one** case (of difference) only -- now it is too broad. Take for instance only the case where you return `c`, and focus your question on what in particular is surprising you in the output.

Comment: Why are you confused that returning different promises creates different results?  Of course it does.  And, when your have a whole bunch of promises that don't actually represent real asynchronous operations with indeterminate timings, then this becomes a largely useless exercise as it's not how real world promise code works.  You can be curious, but aren't likely to learn much that helps you in real world coding.

Comment: I agree with trincot's comment.  This is way too many questions.  Focus one case.  Explain what you do and don't understand about that one case and ask one clear question about that case.

Comment: if you replace code "// (what is the difference between case1 ~ case5)" with "return c;" or "return d;" o "return e:" then the result changes to 9,1,4,2,3,5,8,6,7. 
This is what I want to know, I mean the reason for that.
I think what I want to know is related to real world coding in my work place.

Comment: Can you edit your question and limit it to just one of those? So again, focus on one **one** case only, like the one with `return c`. Put it in the snippet, so the output that you want to ask about is produced by the snippet, and explain which part of the output is unexpected to you.

Comment: I did it as you said. Firstly let's focus on the case of return c, but if possible let me know about other cases briefly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I updated your question to have it focus even more on the `return c` case and only mention the `return d` and `return e` cases as a side note: otherwise you are asking multiple questions which would be a reason to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `a` fulfills, the callback `a_then` will be executed. The return value of that callback determines how `b` resolves. If that `then` callback returns a promise (like `c`), a core feature of promises kicks in: the promise `b` will not simply fulfill with that returned promise object, but will instead remain pending and get "locked-in" to the returned promise: the way promise `c` will settle will determine how `b` will settle -- `b`'s fate is locked-in to that of `c`.

The Promise internal implementation that called `a_then` makes this happen by inspecting the returned value. It detects that this returned value is a *thenable* (it has a `then` method), and will actually plan to **call** that `then` method (`c.then` in this case) as that is the only way to get informed about the settled state of that thenable (`c` in this case). It will pass its own (internal) callback to that `then` method.

This is a callback that is not part of your JS code -- it is provided by the Promise implementation (see the ECMAScript specification on [Promise resolve functions](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-promise-resolve-functions) step 13). Moreover, this call of `c.then` will happen **asynchronously** (see step 14 in the same specification). We can imagine that asynchronous job to look something like this (simplified):

```
function lockin_b(c) {
    c.then(function fulfill_b(value) {
        _fulfill(value)
    });
}
```

...where `_fulfill` is the internal function with which `b` can be settled.

So, in summary, there are two extra asynchronous jobs involved in this locked-in scenario:

1. The asynchronous call of `c.then` by the Promise internals so to lock-in `b` to `c`
2. The asynchronous call of the callback passed to `c.then` when `c` is resolved.

This means that `b` will settle later than when that `return c` would have been omitted, and consequently the `b_then` callback that outputs 5 and 8 will also execute later.

Here is a sequence of events that happen during the execution of that code.

- The first column represents what is executing (the main script, a function initiated from the event loop, or the host that dequeues an item from the PromiseJob queue)
- The second column has the current expression/statement being evaluated
- The columns `a` to `i` represent the state of the promise with that name: `?` for pending, `F` for fulfilled and `R` for resolved, but not yet settled (i.e. locked-in).
- The last column pictures what is present in the PromiseJob queue, managed by the host

| Task | Action | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | PromiseJob queue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Script | `a = Promise.resolve()` | **F** | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |  |
| Script | `b = a.then(a_then)` | F | **?** | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | **`a_then`** |
| Script | `f = b.then(b_then)` | F | ? | - | - | - | **?** | - | - | - | `a_then` |
| Script | **`console.log(9)`** | F | ? | - | - | - | ? | - | - | - | `a_then` |
| Host | dequeue `a_then` | F | ? | - | - | - | ? | - | - | - |  |
| `a_then` | **`console.log(1)`** | F | ? | - | - | - | ? | - | - | - |  |
| `a_then` | `c = Promise.resolve()` | F | ? | **F** | - | - | ? | - | - | - |  |
| `a_then` | `d = c.then(c_then)` | F | ? | F | **?** | - | ? | - | - | - | **`c_then`** |
| `a_then` | `e = d.then(d_then)` | F | ? | F | ? | **?** | ? | - | - | - | `c_then` |
| `a_then` | **`console.log(4)`** | F | ? | F | ? | ? | ? | - | - | - | `c_then` |
| `a_then` | `return c` resolves `b` | F | **R** | F | ? | ? | ? | - | - | - | `c_then`, **`lockin_b`** |
| Host | dequeue `c_then` | F | R | F | ? | ? | ? | - | - | - | `lockin_b` |
| `c_then` | **`console.log(2)`** | F | R | F | ? | ? | ? | - | - | - | `lockin_b` |
| `c_then` | return resolves `d` | F | R | F | **F** | ? | ? | - | - | - | `lockin_b`, **`d_then`** |
| Host | dequeue `lockin_b` | F | R | F | F | ? | ? | - | - | - | `d_then` |
| `lockin_b` | `c.then(fulfill_b)` | F | R | F | F | ? | ? | - | - | - | `d_then`, **`fulfill_b`** |
| `lockin_b` | return | F | R | F | F | ? | ? | - | - | - | `d_then`, `fulfill_b` |
| Host | dequeue `d_then` | F | R | F | F | ? | ? | - | - | - | `fulfill_b` |
| `d_then` | **`console.log(3)`** | F | R | F | F | ? | ? | - | - | - | `fulfill_b` |
| `d_then` | return resolves `e` | F | R | F | F | **F** | ? | - | - | - | `fulfill_b` |
| Host | dequeue `fulfull_b` | F | R | F | F | F | ? | - | - | - |  |
| `fulfull_b` | `_fulfill` | F | **F** | F | F | F | ? | - | - | - | **`b_then`** |
| `fulfull_b` | return | F | F | F | F | F | ? | - | - | - | `b_then` |
| Host | dequeue `b_then` | F | F | F | F | F | ? | - | - | - |  |
| `b_then` | **`console.log(5)`** | F | F | F | F | F | ? | - | - | - |  |
| `b_then` | `g = Promise.resolve()` | F | F | F | F | F | ? | **F** | - | - |  |
| `b_then` | `h = g.then(g_then)` | F | F | F | F | F | ? | F | **?** | - | **`g_then`** |
| `b_then` | `i = h.then(h_then)` | F | F | F | F | F | ? | F | ? | **?** | `g_then` |
| `b_then` | **`console.log(8)`** | F | F | F | F | F | ? | F | ? | ? | `g_then` |
| `b_then` | return resolves `f` | F | F | F | F | F | **F** | F | ? | ? | `g_then` |
| Host | dequeue `g_then` | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | ? | ? |  |
| `g_then` | **`console.log(6)`** | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | ? | ? |  |
| `g_then` | return resolves `h` | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | **F** | ? | **`h.then`** |
| Host | dequeue `h_then` | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | ? |  |
| `h_then` | **`console.log(7)`** | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | ? |  |
| `h_then` | return resolves `i` | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | **F** |  |
| Host | queue is empty | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | F |  |

One can make a similar analysis for when the `return` statement in the `b_then` function returns a different promise. It is the same principle.