# What happens to the second "then" in the promise chain while the Promise is in a pending state?

Tags: javascript, promise

```js
let p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("Data 1st"), 1000)
})
.then((data) => {   // 1ST "then"
    console.log(data)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // 2ND PROMISE
        setTimeout(() => resolve("Data 2nd"), 1000)
    })
}).then((data) => {  // 2ND "then"
    console.log(data)
})
```

I'm confused about promise chaining.

This is how I think JavaScript reads the code:

1. `Let p1 = new Promise` Create a new Promise object.
2. `.then((data) =>...` store the callback function in a variable, that will then be executed when the "`resolved`" executes.
3. `.then((data) =>...` How about the second `then`? It's not referencing the second Promise Object ("`return new Promise...`"). since the Promise is still in Pending state, and the code in the first `then` has not been executed yet.

```
then(handleSuccess) {
  this.promiseChain.push(handleSuccess);
  
  return this;
}
```

https://skilled.dev/course/build-a-javascript-promise

```js
class PromiseSimple {
    constructor(executionFunction) {
      this.promiseChain = [];
      this.handleError = () => {};
  
      this.onResolve = this.onResolve.bind(this);
      this.onReject = this.onReject.bind(this);
  
      executionFunction(this.onResolve, this.onReject);
    }
  
    then(handleSuccess) {
      this.promiseChain.push(handleSuccess);
  
      return this;
    }
  
    catch(handleError) {
      this.handleError = handleError;
  
      return this;
    }
  
    onResolve(value) {
      let storedValue = value;
  
      try {
        this.promiseChain.forEach((nextFunction) => {
          storedValue = nextFunction(storedValue);
        });
      } catch (error) {
        this.promiseChain = [];
  
        this.onReject(error);
      }
    }
  
    onReject(error) {
      this.handleError(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `.then()` returns a Promise.

Comment: There are actually 4 promises in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,  forget about that `PromiseSimple` implementation: it is not compliant to the specification. For instance:

- When the promise resolves, the `then` callbacks are executed synchronously, while that must happen asynchronously.
- Those promises can resolve or reject multiple times. That is not allowed.
- If `then` is called on an already resolved promise, its callback doesn't execute, but it should.
- If a promise resolves to a promise, that promise object is passed to the `then` callback. This should never happen. When a promise resolves to a promise, that first promise should get locked-in to the second promise and not yet call any `then` callbacks.
- ...etc.

There are many more issues, and so using this implementation to understand how promises work will actually lead to misunderstandings instead of helping you.

Now to the steps you have mentioned in your question and wonder about:

> `.then((data) =>...` store the callback function in a variable, that will then be executed when the "resolved" executes.

When the promise resolves, the callback is not executed *immediately*. It will be *scheduled* for execution by placing it in a job queue (the microtask queue). Once the JavaScript engine has no more JS code to execute, it will inspect those job queues, and execute those jobs one after the other. This is what *asynchronous execution* means in the JavaScript world.

> `.then((data) =>...` How about the second `then`? It's not referencing the second Promise Object (`return new Promise`...). since the Promise is still in Pending state, and the code in the first `then` has not been executed yet.

`then()` always returns a new promise object which is pending. This happens synchronously, so you can chain a `then` call to a previous `then` call. All these `then` calls return a new promise (implicitly). If later a promise resolves, the relevant `then` callback will be executed, and that in turn will determine how the next (implicit) promise is resolved, which will in turn schedule the next `then` callback in the chain to be executed.

So step by step:

- The callback to `new Promise(...)` is executed creating a timer with `setTimeout`
- `p1` is assigned the created promise, which is pending
- `.then(...)` is executed (not its callback). It remembers the callback and returns a second promise. Let's call it `p2`. It is also pending.
- The second `.then(...)` is executed. It likewise remembers the callback and returns a third promise. Let's call it `p3`. It is also pending.

So far the synchronous execution. The next thing that happens is the `setTimeout` timeout. `resolve("Data 1st")` is called, and so `p1` is fulfilled with value `"Data 1st"`, which means all relevant callbacks are put on the microtask queue. In this case that means the callback to the first `.then` is placed on the microtask queue.

Again there is nothing more synchronous to execute, so the job from the microtask queue is taken and executed. This is the first `then` callback. It outputs the data, and creates a new promise (explicit) while executing the callback given to the constructor. A new timer is created with `setTimeout` and that new promise (let's call it `p4`) is returned with `return`.

At this moment a crucial attribute of promises kicks in. The value returned with `return` in the `then` callback is the resolution value for promise `p2`. So `p2` is resolved, but since that value is a promise, `p2` is not yet fulfilled (or rejected). Instead it is [*locked-in*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56850392/5459839): although it is resolved, it is still pending(!) as its fulfillment/rejection is now tied up with that of `p4`. And so nothing more happens at this stage.

The next thing is that the second timer expires, and the engine executes the `setTimeout` callback. This executes `resolve("Data 2nd")`, fulfilling promise `p4`. Since `p2` is locked-in to `p4`, also `p2` is fulfilled with that value. As a consequence the callback to the second `then` is now put in the microtask queue -- to be called with that value.

As there is nothing more synchronous to do, the engine picks up the microtask job and executes it. This executes `console.log(data)` with `"Data 2nd"`. There is no explicit return there, so `undefined` is returned, and this becomes the value with which `p3` is fulfilled. As there are no `then` calls on that promise, nothing more is scheduled for execution.