# In the Promise of Javascript, why can't the error be passed to the next chain `.catch()`?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, ecmascript-6

Following is an example:

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  throw new Error('test');
});
promise.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error + ' 1 ');
  return error
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error + ' 2 ');
  return error
})
```

The result for the codes are:

```
Error: test 1
```

As can be seen, the second `catch` call doesn't work.  Does that mean Promise cannot handle error using the chain syntax of `catch`? Is there a way to pass the current error to the next `catch()` call?

Comment: You never rethrow the error. Why would a return value be considered an error to be caught? Use `throw error;` instead, and you should get the behaviour you expect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042068/why-is-onrejected-not-called-following-promise-all-where-promise-reject-incl

Comment: If you *return* something from `catch`, you're saying you've handled the problem and this is the value to continue with. If you haven't handled the problem, *rethrow* rather than returning.

Comment: It's basically like asking why `try { try { throw new Error } catch (e) { log(e); return e } } catch (e) { log(e); return e }` doesn't log twice. Because you already caught the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Returning the error will not make it hit the next `catch`. You need to `throw` the error again:

```
promise.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error + ' 1 ');
  throw error
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error + ' 2 ');
  return error
})
```

```js
-> Error: test 1 
-> Error: test 2
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to throw the error again, as opposed to just returning an error object:

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  throw new Error('test');
});
promise.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error + ' 1 ');
  throw error
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error + ' 2 ');
  return error
})
```

js has no internal notion of "this is an error object so throw it" - if there had been a `then()` clause following your first `catch()`, operation would have been deferred to that, like so:

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  throw new Error('test');
});
promise.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error + ' 1 ');
  return error
}).then(function(error) {
  console.log(error + ' 2 ');
  return error
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I wonder what "this is an error object so throw` feature would look like or even what it would mean.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I edited my wording so I'm gunna delete all my comments to clean up the answer :)